# Edit css of element.style

Tags: html, css

I want to edit the `overflow-y` property in element.style .

But I could not understand how to do it.

[image]

Can I use `.div>.div>.div>.div>.div>.div>{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}`

in css file.

Comment: this is inline css.it is written in element's style attribute or added styles by javascript.you have to check first which way it is added.

Comment: you can check this by checking the source code `(ctrl+u)` if no styles in sourcecode java script have added styles later in that case use chrome developer tools and add breakpoint to attribute modification `(break on > attribute modification)`,after refresh you can see codes responsible for the style change and you can edit it.but if styles exist in the source stlyes added by style attribute then you can just change the syles using elements style attribute.

Comment: I recommand you to learn some css :https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha  Can I use `.div>.div>.div>.div>.div>.div>{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}`

Comment: @defen without knowing your html i cannot say.if it's adding by js your styles will be replaced by js

Answer (score 0):

To edit something in Developer Tools, just right-click and edit the property.

Comment: for me it's a single left click on the property's _value_ to edit it (left click on 'auto')

Comment: I want to edit it in css file . For that what should I write?